# Server running on a loop and reloading the same file again and again

Tags: python, django

I am running a project in my virtualenv on Django but constantly getting this issue the error I get is

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/Users/Saujan/Desktop/FinalProject/netscan/apps/core/
templatetags/general_info.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 23, 2019 - 15:48:31
Django version 2.2, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/Users/Saujan/Desktop/FinalProject/netscan/apps/core/
templatetags/general_info.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 23, 2019 - 15:48:33
Django version 2.2, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/Users/Saujan/Desktop/FinalProject/netscan/apps/core/
templatetags/general_info.py changed, reloading.
(netscan_venv) Saujan:netscan Saujan$
```

Comment: There is no error: check identified no issues.

Comment: hi brett i tried uploading pic but it didn't work i get the same message repeating all the time and if i try to open the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ connection is refused

Comment: the key is in this part of the output `/Users/Saujan/Desktop/FinalProject/netscan/apps/core/
templatetags/general_info.py changed, reloading.` It is detecting a change in a file and therefore reloading the server... is there some process modifying the content or attributes of that file?

Comment: thank you guys found the error actually one of my file was constantly updating

Comment: What could be the possible causes for a file to get updated constantly? I'm facing the same issue although I don't know any reason why a particular file is getting updated constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case is that the folder where I had the project was getting synced by dropbox. So it was in constant change. Once the synced was done I was able to run the server without any issue.